# Problem with iterator variable, Oracle docs

Tags: java, foreach

I was going through [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for `For-Each Loop` and there it is mentioned

> The iterator variable occurs three times in each loop: that is two chances to get it wrong.

Why there is two chances to get it wrong?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: It means that there is an identifier that is used three times. The second and third uses both have to match the first, otherwise your program won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in relation to this code snippet:

```
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
    for (Iterator<TimerTask> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
        i.next().cancel();
}
```

It is saying that when you refer to the iterator after its declaration (`i.hasNext()`; `i.next()`) you might accidentally refer to some other iterator variable that is in scope, or omit one, or call `i.next()` more than once in the loop, or something like that.

In contrast, a for-each loop:

```
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
    for (TimerTask t : c)
        t.cancel();
}
```

you don't refer to the iterator (you *can't* refer to it), so you can't make the same errors.

Comment: Apprently you have crystall ball, why didn't you improve the question first?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I am not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Which part? If you know that the question was incorrectly written, why didn't you improve its quality first?